# Find flexible element with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium

I am currently trying to figure out how to click on an element on a website that appears randomly. It is a fish that appears in the water. The water is a 4x4 table, where there is a vector graph of a fish in every cell. When the fish "appears" the opacity of the fish changes from "invisible" to black and back to "invisible".

I have the xpaths for the cells/the whole table but I have no idea how identify the fish.

Invisible fish:

```
<dic class = "col-25 fishcell">
<img src="/img/items/fish.png" class = "fish f41" style= "display: none;">
</div>
```

Visible fish:

```
<dic class = "col-25 fishcell">
<img src="/img/items/fish.png" class = "fish f41 catch" style= "display: inline; opacity: (1);">
</div>
```

The opacity value goes back to 0 and the fish is gone. The fish is visible for about a second or 2.

As you can see, the class changes with an added "catch" as well. I only worked with static website objects so far. In theory, my code would have to constantly check if any of the values withing the grid change, if a change in the class name or in the style is detected, the script would ne to pause, click, then go back into the loop again.

You need an account to try out the game, so I cant provide any example code, I am helpfull for any hints how I can check flexible elements with RSelenium.

EDIT 1:
I found a way to identify the visible fish:

```
for (i in 1:120) {
  for (x in 1:4) {
    link <- paste("//*[@id=\"fishinwater\"]/div[1]/div[", x, sep = "")
    link <- paste(link,"]/img", sep = "" )
    grid <- remDr$findElement(value = link)
    if (grid$getElementAttribute("style") != "display: none;" ) {
      grid$highlightElement
      print("WE FOUND A FISH")
    }
    }
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

- This loop checks all grids for visible fishs by checking the "style" attribute of the fish.img. If it is "display:none", there is no fish, if it changes to anything else, the fish is visible.
- the (i in 1:120) is just a random number to check 120 times.
- the (x in 1:4) is necessary, because each row of the 4x4 grid has a different xpath
- $highlight and the print command are just for visible representation

The script works so far but, as @neuron mentioned, I dont know if it very efficient (I am actually pretty sure it isnt). I am unfamiliar "keeping stuff running" other than with a loop. Further help in improving the code is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Showing the html is only really useful if you were going to scrape the site. Since the fish is only visible for a second or two, then a web scraper will be extremely inefficient.

Comment: I don't `r` but I am answer this in Python-Selenium, let me know if you are open for that.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I edited my post, because I started to get some ideas (ofc after I made the stackoverflow post and putting the thing aside for a night). I could finally add some code examples.